# Can Junkrat's RIP-Tire be healed?

Tags: overwatch

While playing Mercy in competitive play, I noticed that I could view the health my allied Junkrat's RIP-Tire. I was even shown a critical health indicator when the Tire had nearly been destroyed.

This made me wonder whether it was possible to heal an allied Junkrat's RIP-Tire, similar to D.Va's mech during a self-destruct.

I know that a RIP-Tire can be healed using health packs, but I'm not sure whether or not it can be healed by support heroes like Ana or Lucio.

Comment: I don't recall any time I've ever been able to target a rip-tire on mercy (100+ hours) but I also never knew traps used health packs. Mercy is a definite no from me, but Ana is a possibility in my mind since she doesn't require a lock on like Mercy staff.

Comment: As someone who plays lots of Junkrat I can also say that I've never seen the healing from Lucio/Soldier and shield generator from Sym do anything either.

Answer (score 2):

**You can not heal any Hero deployables or buildables in any way** (with the exception of Torbjörn healing his own Turrets).

Though previously it was possible to heal Torbjorn's turrets and Junkrat's tire with health pick-ups, that was patched out at some point without making it into the patch notes.

Some examples of buildables not being healed:

- [Torbjörn's Turret on Health Pickup](https://gfycat.com/AlienatedExemplaryIndigobunting)
- [Symettra's Shield Generator on Health Pickup](https://gfycat.com/BiodegradableCornyDogwoodclubgall)
- [Junkrat's Rip-Tire on Health Pickup](https://gfycat.com/FeistyMixedDaddylonglegs)

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you [edit] your post and re-upload the Gfycat media through SE's Imgur instance to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE's Imgur instance. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any source for the following apart from my own personal experience:

The Rip tire shares the same mechanic that the trap, torb's turret and Symetra's ultimate has:

**They have HP that can heal from health packs but not from heroes.**

Comment: Sym teleports/shield generators can heal from health packs? No way!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Way, here's a relevant discussion https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754377036

Comment: Are support heroes shown critical health warnings for Torbjörn's turret or Symmetra's shield?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Torb's turret is a no go for anyone, only Torb can heal it. To the best of my knowledge, I've never seen low health indicators for Torb/Sym equipment as a support.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The low health indicator was why I wasn't sure about Junkrat's tire. Unlike Torb's turret or Symmetra's shield, the tire is treated as a playable character which can be controlled independently, similar to D.Va's mech