# Does Sombra gain Ultimate charge by healing Junkrat's RIP-Tire?

Tags: overwatch

Sombra's Hack ability allows her to increase the spawn rate of Health pickups on the maps, and as per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/314800/183611) she gets 1 point of ultimate charge per 1 point of friendly hero hp healed.

It is also possible for Junkrat's Ultimate Tire to roll over Health pickups and get healed.

If a friendly Junkrat's tire gets healed by a hacked health pickup does the Sombra who hacked it get any Ultimate charge? Or can Sombra only get Ultimate charge by healing herself or friendly heroes?

Comment: Not sure Torb's turret gets healed from it, pretty sure it's him alone that can heal it. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313555/can-junkrats-rip-tire-be-healed

Comment: I remember using the Torb Turret on health pack to great effect on the large health pack next to Point A of Volskaya Industries. But it as been a long time since I tried it so it could have been patched out.

Comment: Also apparently the health pack healing works with Symmetra Teleporters and Shield Generators, but I have never tried it myself. So it would be interesting if Sombra gets ult charge from healing those too.

Comment: @n_palum You are correct, [Torb turrets no longer use medpacks](https://gfycat.com/WeepyDistortedJoey), I must have missed the patchnotes when they changed it :/

Comment: @StevenVascellaro There seems to be a lot of interest in this question, I think it will boil down to who ever is able to get three people in game for testing first... As for the torb no health packs thing, it doesn't really answer the actual question, which is does sombra get ult charge from friendly buildings (that she can heal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sombra can not gain ultimate charge from healing Junkrat's Riptire, as Junkrat's Riptire (and other buildables/deployables) can not be healed by health packs.**

The question is flawed, as Blizzard patched out the ability for buildables/deployables to be healed by health pickups, though it was never mentioned in the patch notes.

[See here, Junkrat's Rip Tire is no longer healed by Health pick-ups.](https://gfycat.com/FeistyMixedDaddylonglegs) As well as [this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313555/can-junkrats-rip-tire-be-healed).

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide the precise patch notes right now, but I remember that the patch notes revoking the possibility for torbjörn's turret to use med-packs, were stated somewhat along the meaning That nothing but heroes are able to use health packs from that specific patch on.

(IIRC it even stated healing in general (except special means) is reserved for heroes only)

What so ever is the case, for your specific question:

No she can't get charge for healing constructs, since constructs can't be healed by hero designated heals. But of course she can get charge by dealing damage and not only by healing friendly heroes with hacked packs.